# Não cadastrar na faixa de horario se já existir

Tags: php, mysql

Como não cadastrar eventos na faixa de horário que já está cadastrada ?

**Exemplo:** Tenho um evento no BD com inicio as 18:00 e termino as 22:00, preciso que caso o usuário tente cadastrar um novo evento das 19:00 as 23:00 o sistema não permita pois está na faixa de horário já cadastrada...

> O BD esta com essa estrutura: inicio - varchar(500) - exemplo de
>   cadastro "18:00" e termino - varchar(500) - exemplo de cadastro "22:00"

A Query Mysql para PHP 5.4:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO compromiso (termino, inicio) VALUES ('$termino', '$inicio')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Ajudaria se a coluna fosse `DATETIME`, tem chance de você alterar?

Comment: posso alterar! como fica o formato da hora ? 22:00:00 ?

Comment: na verdade acho que seria melhor para TIME né ?

Comment: Se as faixas nunca atravessam de um dia pro outro, `TIME` é melhor sim.

Comment: na verdade elas passam de um dia para o outro, mas tenho outros campos com o dia, mes e ano...

Comment: Já tentou usar between com um select into?

Comment: @Patrick, posta um exemplo como resposta...

Comment: Não posso, mas dê uma olhada nessa resposta, talvez te ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3025332/3029543

Comment: Ah, evite usar `mysql`, ao invés disso, use `mysqli`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isso mais facilmente você precisa modificar os campos para datetime e gravar a data e hora completa neles por exemplo: `2014-08-23 18:00`.
E antes de inserir um novo compromisso, tem que fazer uma consulta para ver se resulta algum registro, comparando se horas de inicio ou termino estão dentro das novas horas de inicio e termino, como no exemplo abaixo:

**Edit:** Inclui mais duas condições, para verificar se as novas horas de inicio e termino não estão totalmente dentro de um compromisso já registrado.

```
SELECT * FROM compromisso WHERE
(inicio BETWEEN '2014-08-23 19:00' AND '2014-08-23 23:00')
OR (termino BETWEEN '2014-08-23 19:00' AND '2014-08-23 23:00')
OR ('2014-08-23 19:00' BETWEEN inicio AND termino)
OR ('2014-08-23 23:00' BETWEEN inicio AND termino)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b52e3/1)

Comment: A query do SQLFiddle poderia estar numa trigger , gerando um erro se houver evento já cadastrado, forma simples de garantir a integrigade.

Answer (score 5):

```
select * 
from compromisso 
where (
      ('2014-08-23 19:00' between inicio and termino
       or
       '2014-08-23 23:00' between inicio and termino)
       or
       (inicio BETWEEN '2014-08-23 19:00' AND '2014-08-23 23:00' 
        or 
        termino BETWEEN '2014-08-23 19:00' AND '2014-08-23 23:00')
      )
```

Creio que deva ter um teste "duplo" , sem chance de fazer um teste aqui agora todavia.